# Conv1d Pytorch on the columns of a matrix

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I would like to compute, in the most efficient way, the following operation:

```
cc = nn.Conv1d(1,1,3,1,1,bias=False)
U = torch.randn(1,1,10,10)
V = torch.zeros_like(U)
for i in range(10):
    V[:,:,:,i] = cc(U[:,:,:,i])
```

In other words, I would like to apply a 1d convolution on the columns of the input U. Of course the for loop is too slow and I am sure there is a more efficient way to solve the problem. However, I can not find any idea to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a 2D convolution with a rectangular shape window ie. `1x3`:

```
conv = nn.Conv2d(1,1, kernel_size=(1,3), padding=1, bias=False)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was such a simple solution but I didn't think about that because I'm too biased towards squared 2d filters